# Excess Blank Space in Bar Graph Excel

Tags: excel

[image]

As you can see in the image, I'm getting a lot of blank space on the right side of my graph. When I shrink the graph horizontally, it just shrinks my data. As a note, I have the axis set up based on text rather than date, since you can't choose weekly, so it was putting large gaps between my bars, which I was also trying to avoid.

Comment: Seems something went wrong with the data selection. Right click on the chart and see select data and formulas for series and category in there.

Answer (score 0):

I create a similar graph to yours and everything looks fine as you can see below. I also pasted axis options onto the screenshot for you to double check.
Also there may be some blank rows in the graph's scope which we cannot see on screen.

[image: my graph]